# Slice the middle of a nd array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with shape `(20,50,100,500,500)` and I want to slice the array based on the 3rd dimension, let's say 40/60.

All that I can think of is to do. `array[:,:,:40,:,:]` and `array[:,:,60:,:,:]`, but how does one connect those without messing up the dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

I used np.stack, setting `axis=2` as following:

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(2,2,2,2,2)                                                                                                                                       
>>> a1 = a[:,:,:1,:,:]                                                                                                                                                  
>>> a2 = a[:,:,1:,:,:]                                                                                                                                                  
>>> b = np.stack((a1,a2), axis=2)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate on the right axis:

```
np.concatenate([ array[:,:,:40,:,:], array[:,:,60:,:,:] ], axis=2)
```